# How would i go about censoring adult language in my book for school?

Tags: creative-writing, picture-books

I'm making a book just for fun, but I'm using a device provided by my school. I (a 12-year-old male) am writing a book with some curse words in it. Later I got an Email from my district, it was lecturing me about how I shouldn't use curse words.

I'm still keeping the bossy attitude of one of my characters, but I don't know how to censor my book.

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE! I'm afraid that our [Terms of Service](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service) require users to be 13 or over, for data protection reasons. I hope you'll come back once you're old enough to use the site.

Answer (score 4):

A long accepted practice is to make up words that are fairly obviously the real curse words, but aren't.

On the TV Series Battlestar Galactica (long before you were born), they needed the rough and tough soldier characters to curse, but network TV (back then) prohibited the use of most curse words, especially the word "fuck".

Instead, the characters used "frak." As in, "Frak you," "It's a frakking mess," etc. Viewers got used to it, they started using "frak" themselves. It's obviously a curse, and obviously means "fuck", but "frak" is not a censored word on network TV, and after a few episodes everybody adapted to it.

Do the same for your book. Start your made-up curses with the same letter, if possible end them with the same sound; that's enough.

On the series "The Good Place" (more recently, a comedy) the characters were magically prohibited from cursing, when they tried to say "fuck" it came out "fork". "Shit" came out as "Shift", I think. It was for comic effect, so a frustrated character says "You know what? Fork this shift." And the other characters are shocked.

I'd prefer the made up word, if you ever wanted to, you could do a mass edit and change all "frak" to "fuck". All "shist" to "shit."

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that you don't have to have your character curse in order to be bossy and arrogant. You can have that character be insulting without necessarily curse.

Another method I have seen in several books: wherever there is a curseword, add a line. Take the following statement:

*We're coming for you, you --.*

It is quite evident that a curseword was spoken, yet at the same time you don't have the word in the story.
Finally, you can just say, *Character XYZ cursed under his breath/swore/muttered under his breath*. Just saying that shows the reader what was done without having the language itself.
Little things like this can help a lot.

Comment: _"You can have that character be insulting without necessarily curse."_ For many good examples just watch Rowan Atkinson in "Black Adder". Much better than cursing.